# Adding vline to time-series ggplot collapses X asis?

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I have ts data that I draw with quarterly legend:

```
z <- as.zoo(my_data)
breaks <- seq(min(time(z)), max(time(z)), .25);
autoplot(z, geom="line",ylim=c(0,75)) + scale_x_yearqtr(breaks = breaks, format = "%yQ%q")
```

I'd like to draw a vertical line at a predetermined position (let's say at 1975-08-01).

The problem is, then I add "+ geom_vline", I get a really weird collapsed chart. Obviously, I have no true idea what I'm doing but I've tried this:

```
+ geom_vline(xintercept=as.Date("1975-08-01"))
+ geom_vline(xintercept=as.numeric(as.Date("1975-08-01")))
```

and as offsets (not sure how it goes):

```
+ geom_vline(xintercept=as.numeric(z[c(10,11)]))
+ geom_vline(xintercept=as.numeric(z[10]))
+ geom_vline(xintercept=3)
```

This is what happens (without geom_vline it is OK):

[image: plot image]

How can I put an offset ("draw vline at datapoint X") or data ("1975-08-01")?

What am I doing wrong?

---

Adding some data.

> dput(z)
>   structure(c(NA, NA, NA, 56.0775, 58.53, 58.17, 61.5025, 57.71, 
>   56.5075, 53.9375, 47.345, 48.6975, 53.15, 60.3125, 60.2, 65.1025, 
>   63.445, 57.86, 62.1225, 62.19, 64.075, 71.7725, 69.565, 63.4575000000001, 
>   59.2175, 53.8525, 53.4175, 50.1475, 50.9, 50.0675, 52.6925, 59.9325, 
>   59.8625, 61.8375, 57.655, 50.23, 47.8775, 39.5475, 40.1375, 43.2075, 
>   44.885, 48.115), index = structure(c(1974, 1974.08333333333, 
>   1974.16666666667, 1974.25, 1974.33333333333, 1974.41666666667, 
>   1974.5, 1974.58333333333, 1974.66666666667, 1974.75, 1974.83333333333, 
>   1974.91666666667, 1975, 1975.08333333333, 1975.16666666667, 1975.25, 
>   1975.33333333333, 1975.41666666667, 1975.5, 1975.58333333333, 
>   1975.66666666667, 1975.75, 1975.83333333333, 1975.91666666667, 
>   1976, 1976.08333333333, 1976.16666666667, 1976.25, 1976.33333333333, 
>   1976.41666666667, 1976.5, 1976.58333333333, 1976.66666666667, 
>   1976.75, 1976.83333333333, 1976.91666666667, 1977, 1977.08333333333, 
>   1977.16666666667, 1977.25, 1977.33333333333, 1977.41666666667
>   ), class = "yearmon"), frequency = 12, class = c("zooreg", "zoo"))

Comment: It looks like the `vline` you are trying to add (1975-08-01) is earlier than `min(time(z))`. You only have breaks and ticks for the period between `min(time(z))` and `max(time(z))`, 1975-08-01 appears to not be included in this range. What is the value of `min(time(z))` ?

Comment: It's in time format:> min(time(z))
[1] "Jan 1974" - so I guess the question in, how can I put the line in "Aug 1975" :-)

Comment: It could be easier to answer with a reproducible example, with a piece or your data, could you provide us a `dput(z)` and edit your question with the result ?

Comment: Well, this answered me, thanks - geom_vline(xintercept=as.numeric(1975.67)) works :)

Answer (score 1):

The index class of `z` has class `"yearmon"

```
class(index(z))
## [1] "yearmon"
```

so the `xintercept=` should be specified consistently, i.e. also as a `"yearmon"` object:

```
p <- autoplot(z, ylim=c(0,75)) + 
   scale_x_yearqtr(breaks = breaks, format = "%yQ%q")

p + geom_vline(xintercept = as.yearmon("1975-08"))
```

Any other valid specification of a `"yearmon"` object would work as well, e.g.

```
p + geom_vline(xintercept = as.yearmon(1975 + (8-1) / 12))

p + geom_vline(xintercept = as.yearmon(as.Date("1975-08-01")))
```

Answer (score 0):

As bVa pointed out, I used dput to see the format of index.
As dates are stored in decimal, the solution is to use simple decimal value. 1975.67 for aug 1975.

geom_vline(xintercept=as.numeric(1975.67))